# Better way to response to AJAX from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have one javascript file which sends AJAX request to php file, which fetch some data from database. If php finds any data it return it as json object in response, but when it does not find any recrod in database based on query, it return a message something like "not match found".
It means javascript either get string message in "not match found" or json object.
I am trying to check if xmlhttp.responseText is json object or a string, but have not been succedeed. Any idea about how to solve this problem?
Should I convert "not match found" string into a json and send back to javascript and then parse it or there is any better way to solve this?
Thank you
BR

Comment: I'd personally send a JSON response either way, and then have `status` and `message` keys in the JSON. If you really want to check the type of the response, you can probably use the aptly-named `typeof`.

Comment: I think status and message keys are better option. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to parse your error message "No match found". There's two options: either create an `if/else` statement in the PHP file that the ajax calls, or you can attempt to encode the JSON in the php file and if it's unsuccessful, you can just write out a "No match found" message in the error part. I highly recommend using the `$.ajax` call because it can handle the responses better.

JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myFile.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
         var myNewJsonData = data;
         alert(myNewJsonData);
    },
    error: function() {
         alert("No match found.");
    }
});
```

PHP (myFile.php)

```
<?php
    //Do your query business and stuff here

    //Now let's say you get back or store some array that looks like this for example
    $myArray = array('name' => 'Mike', 'age' => 20);


    /* Now attempt to create a JSON representation of the array using json_encode() */
    echo json_encode($myArray);        
?>
```

When you echo it out, it gets sent back through either the `$.ajax`'s call `success` or `error` function as a parameter (which I named `data`), depending on whether or not there was an error reported back. If there was not, then `success` is called, and if there is an error, well then you can guess which one gets called. `json_encode` will create a JSON representation of the array of data that you get back from your query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, can't you just print out an error using something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myphpfile.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.info);
    },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(xhr);
        }

     });
```

Then do something inside of the `error` block?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I totally agree with Patrick Q's comment, there is another option that has not been mentioned.  You could also set the Content-Type of the response to indicate if it's json or text:

```
@header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
```

and

```
@header( 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
```

or even,

```
@header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
```

Then you could check the response's content type to make a decision:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "xxx", 
  data: "xxx", 
  success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
      var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
      if (ct.indexOf('html') > -1) {
          //do something
      } else
      if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
          // handle json here
      } 
  }
});
```

A.